# Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm for bidirectional iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

Is there any Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm implementation for bidirectional iterators? In Boost.Algorithm there is version for random-access iterators.

Comment: I'm not sure if one can do it efficiently. We need to make long "jumps" over the input string when we don't have a transition.

Comment: It's actually doable (there's even a purely functional linear time implementation), but it requires a little bit more memory.

Comment: I know it. But i did not find any docs about it.

Comment: Well, you can do it yourself. You just need to store the next char along with the value of `p[i]` for all `i` in the pattern.

Comment: Oh, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look a standard implementation. The only place where we actually need random access is comparing `pattern[i]` and the current character after making jump `i = p[i]`. Instead of accessing `pattern[i]` directly (which would require linear time in the worst case for bidirectional iterators), we can store the next character `c` in the pattern along with `p[i]` when we build the transitions table.

However, it's not that useful. Storing a symbol for each `i` is essentially the same thing as copying the pattern to a structure that supports random access, so it would be easier to do it directly.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do you know any effective search algorithms for bidirectional iterators?